# In MongoDB, how can I retrieve an item and then add to an embedded document within it?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to do something similar to the following

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/embedded-documents.html

However instead of new BlogPost I'm trying to retrieve then add as follows

```
function addComment(id, comment, callback) {
    Post.findOne(id, function(err, post) {
    post.comments.push(comment);
    });
}
```

I'm getting

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined
```

What am I doing wrong? I left out the saving code for simplification it is crashing even without trying to save.

Comment: The error doesn't directly come from any code you posted. Do you have a stack trace. Does mongoose work in general (try another example)? Did you initiate it correctly? Do you have a Post class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the `id` parameter is an ObjectId or string (and not a query object), you should be calling `findById` instead of `findOne`.